# Back up post tags

Tags: posts, tags

What is the best way to back up tags on posts? I want to delete all existing tags on all post types, but want to be able to restore them if something goes wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just export the wp_terms table (or *_terms if you have a custom prefix) as a .sql file, then truncate the table. This will clear them all.

If you want to put them back on, just import the .sql file you just created.

Hope this helps